# Nested Loop Problem for MIPS (Prime Numbers)

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

Hi I'm new to MIPS and I know my code is a tad bit messy, here's a prime numbers code I've written and it keeps bugging me, but I cant seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. I think the issue is with the nested loops since I'm not very used to using the loops using MIPS. I've been using MARS for coding MIPS and every time I run it, it just freezes.

Here's my a section of my code where I coded the loop part for prime numbers below:

```
    #Outer loop 
L2: move $t3, $zero
    # Inner loop
L1: remu $t4, $t1, $t2
bne $t4, $zero, I
move $t3, $t5
I:  
blt $t2, $t1 L1
bne $t3, $zero, P
li  $v0, 1          
move    $a0, $t1       
syscall
li  $v0, 4      
la  $a0, space
syscall   
     
P:  
move $t2, $t6
bgt  $t1, $t0, E    
j L2
E:  li  $v0,    10  
    syscall     # call operating sys
end:    jr  $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are are getting this error is that you have forgotten to add an increment (variable i and k) for the loop, causing the error, the loop will not terminate (just like a while loop) what your code needs is a line

```
add $t1, $t1, $t5
```

In the ‘P’ branch/loop that you have created
And

```
add $t2, $t2, $t5
```

In the ‘I’ branch/loop that you have created
so your code would look something like

```
    #Outer loop 
L2: move $t3, $zero
    # Inner loop
L1: remu $t4, $t1, $t2
bne $t4, $zero, I
move $t3, $t5
I: add $t2, $t2, $t5   # increment k
blt $t2, $t1 L1
bne $t3, $zero, P
li  $v0, 1         
move    $a0, $t1     
syscall
li  $v0, 4   
la  $a0, space
syscall         
P:  add $t1, $t1, $t5   # increment i
move $t2, $t6
bgt  $t1, $t0, E    
j L2
E:  li  $v0,    10 
    syscall     
end:    jr  $ra
```

I hope that helps!